# Best way to rebase and merge all changes from another branch

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I normally pull my coworker's feature branch when it's ready to merge into master, but first I rebase it on top of the latest master and squash down the work-in-progress commits into a single commit (my coworker is a designer and uses a GitHub GUI).

I ran into an issue when my coworker had included in his feature branch a merge commit from master. The problem is, he included feature changes in his merge commit that were getting removed during the rebase. As far as I know, `git rebase master` normally ignores merge commits, and `git rebase --preserve-merges master` wasn't doing any rebasing all.

I came across various solutions for generating a patch, but most of them either omitted the merge commit or omitted some needed binary files. I finally came up with this solution:

```
git checkout master
git diff --binary master...feature-branch > my.patch
git apply -3 my.patch
git commit
rm my.patch
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Did these feature changes occur in isolated commits which could be ignored?  If not, then I would personally just bite the bullet and deal with the merge conflicts.

Comment: `As far as I know, git rebase master normally ignores merge commits` ... no, this doesn't sound right to me.  Why would Git treat a merge commit differently than any other type of commit, out of the box?

Comment: Some feature changes were in their own commits, some were directly in the merge commit. I'm not sure why, but every time I tried to rebase, the changes included directly in the merge commit disappeared, and the merge commit didn't appear in the new history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This generates a file called `my.patch`, applies it using a 3 way merge, commits the changes, then removes the patch file.

```
git checkout master
git diff --binary master...feature-branch > my.patch
git apply -3 my.patch
git commit
rm my.patch
```